# How to Limit Google Map Zoom

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to limit how far the user can zoom out in a Google Map in Android? I don't want the user to be able to zoom out far enough to see more than one Earth. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can disable the built in zoom and add you own bottons and changing your zoon on click. you will be able to disable zoom out for a certain level.

**Important** I think the user may always be able to scroll horizontally.